# Использование списков зависимостей с Dockerfile

Tags: инспекция-кода, docker, apt-get, pip

Способ 1, который я встречаю во многих популярных докерфайлах:

Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get install fizz=1.2.3 \
                    buzz=3.2.1
RUN pip install foo==1.2.3 \
                bar==3.2.1
```

Способ 2, который мне кажется логичным и правильным, но я его не встречаю:

Dockerfile:

```
RUN cat requirements.apt | xargs apt-get install
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

requirements.apt:

```
fizz=1.2.3
buzz=3.2.1
```

requirements.txt:

```
foo==1.2.3
bar==3.2.1
```

Всё-таки, как правильно указывать зависимости в докерфайле? Есть ли недостатки у второго способа?

Comment: чем именно второй способ правильнее?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman я привык так устанавливать зависимости в других случаях, поэтому и здесь это кажется логичным. Но ваши аргументы убедительны.

Comment: Вообще не вижу принципиальной разницы, но в первом случае зависимости легко выносятся в переменные окружения. Что именно до зависимостей приложения (или специализированного окружения) - как правило, они идут в отдельном файле (composer.json, package.json, Gemfile, requirements.txt, etc.)

Comment: @etki а когда это может быть полезно?

Comment: @NickVolynkin это дает возможность конечному пользователю быстро разрешить потенциальный конфликт сбором нового образа с другой версией зависимости + если где-то еще в докерфайле надо поработать с конкретной библиотекой, то каждое обновление зависимости превратится в пляску с поиском забытых указаний старой версии. Глобального счастья, конечно, не несет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На мой взгляд первый способ (по сравнению со вторым) имеет ряд преимуществ:

- чтобы понять, что будет установлено достаточно отрыть 1 файл
- чтобы понять, чем отличаются контейнеры достаточно сравнить 1 файл
- в контейнер не попадают лишние файлы
- не создаются дополнительные слои

Но я бы в первом способе выполнил все установки в одном `RUN` и еще почистил кэши и пр. - слой получиться меньшего размера.

Comment: У pip тоже можно почистить кэш? Про apt знаю, как.

Comment: я бы pip переделал в пакеты и устанавливал бы так.

Comment: не понимаю, как?

Comment: тут важно уточнить, какой контейнер мы собираем - дев или прод?

Comment: один контейнер будет собирать сайты, другой запускать ansible, то и другое на GitLab docker runner.

Comment: то есть сами контейнеры в продакшн окружение не попадают? тогда можно не делать пакеты. иначе для создания пакетов из pip можно использовать https://fpm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/python.html

Comment: Понял как, теперь не понимаю, зачем. Всё равно питоновое окружение придется тянуть, хоть традиционным путём, хоть в пакете, разве нет? Может быть, я уже новый вопрос задам об этом?

Comment: все ради безопасности. задайте.